# dad code method range of object _worksheet failed

Tags: excel, macos

my code is supports to move tabs when I click on it but I keep getting the **method range of object _worksheet failed** error, any ideas to fix it?

if you need more information just tell me

```
Sub switchhorizontaltabs()
Dim SelCol As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long
With Sheet11
SelCol = .Range("B2").Value
.Range("5:396").EntireRow.Hidden = True
FirstRow = 5 + ((SelCol - 5) * 50)
.Range(FirstRow & ":" & FirstRow + 49).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End With
End Sub 

Sub weeklytabs2()
Dim SelCol As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long
With Sheet11
SelCol = .Range("B3").Value
.Range("4:403").EntireRow.Hidden = True
.Range("404:404").EntireRow.Hidden = False
.Range("405:454").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End With
End Sub

Sub switchhorizontaltabs2()
Dim SelCol As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long
With Sheet11
SelCol = .Range("B4").Value
.Range("405:780").EntireRow.Hidden = True
FirstRow = 405 + ((SelCol - 405) * 50)
**.Range(FirstRow & ":" & FirstRow + 49).EntireRow.Hidden = False**
End With
End Sub

Sub Weeklytabs1()
Dim SelCol As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long
With Sheet11
SelCol = .Range("B3").Value
.Range("4:396").EntireRow.Hidden = False
.Range("404:780").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End With
End Sub
```

the value of the `Firstrow is -19595 not 405

the error is code at the bottom `.Range(FirstRow & ":" & FirstRow + 49).EntireRow.Hidden = False`

Comment: What is the value of `FirstRow`? Also, no screenshots of code please. [Edit] your question with the code as text.

Comment: What is the output in the Immediate Window of `Debug.Print FirstRow`, if you add that before the problematic line?

Comment: FirstRow is -19595

Comment: That's your problem. There is no such thing as a negative row. `FirstRow = 405 + ((SelCol - 405) * 50)` has an issue.

Comment: how do I fix it?

Comment: You have to ensure that `SelCol` is `>=405`. Or fix your math in that calculation, it may be off.

Comment: thank you so much, now i just need to figure out how to rewrite that math for it to work,  thank you, at least now i know what the issue is